# Wait for webview to load before completing execution in Vue + Capacitor mobile app

Tags: vue.js, webview, capacitor, onesignal

I am using Onesignal for push notifications in my **Vue + Capacitor app**. When a notification is clicked, I want to redirect the user to a specific page and perform some API calls. However, the notifyListeners function is fired too early and finds no listeners since the JavaScript isn't done loading yet, This occurs when the app is closed and by that I mean the app is not active(**Not opened at all**) but when the app is running or in the background (**Opend but not in view**) the listeners are already added and it functions as expected. Is there a way to wait for the webview to properly load before proceeding to notifyListeners?

**Incase you wonderd why I went this route I had alot of issues with the capacitor plugin so I went native.**

**Versions**:

- Capacitor 5
- Vue 2

Android

```
import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import com.onesignal.notifications.IDisplayableNotification;


@CapacitorPlugin(name = "OneSignalBridge")

public class OneSignalBridge extends Plugin {
    private static final String EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA = "OneSignalBridgeGetData";

    @Override
    public void load() {
        OneSignal.getNotifications().addClickListener(event -> {
            IDisplayableNotification notification = (IDisplayableNotification) event.getNotification();
            JSONObject data = notification.getAdditionalData();
            this.sendNotificationData(data);
        });
    }
    @PluginMethod()
    public void setExternalIdToOneSignal(PluginCall call){
        String userId = call.getString("userId");
        OneSignal.login(userId);
    }

    @PluginMethod()
    public void removeExternalIdToOneSignal(PluginCall call){
        OneSignal.logout();
    }
    public void sendNotificationData(JSONObject data) {
            JSObject notificationDataObject = new JSObject();
            notificationDataObject.put("data", data);
            notifyListeners(EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA, notificationDataObject);
    }
}
```

IOS

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor
import OneSignalFramework
@objc(OneSignalBridge)
public class OneSignalBridge: CAPPlugin,OSNotificationClickListener {
    private let EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA = "OneSignalBridgeGetData"
    override public func load() {
        
           // Add the notification click listener here
        OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener(self)
       }
    @objc public func onClick(event: OSNotificationClickEvent) {
        // Get the notification that was clicked.
                let notification = event.notification

                // Get the notification data.
                let data = notification.additionalData
        
            // Send the notification data to Capacitor.
            self.sendNotificationData(data)
        }
    @objc func setExternalIdToOneSignal(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE)
        let userId = call.getString("userId") ?? ""
        OneSignal.login(userId)
    }
    
    @objc func removeExternalIdToOneSignal(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        OneSignal.logout()
    }
    
    public func sendNotificationData(_ data: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data ?? [:], options: []),
           let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            var dataObject = JSObject()
            dataObject["data"] = jsonString
            
            notifyListeners(EVENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA, data: dataObject, retainUntilConsumed: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

So

I Tried checking if capacitor comes with methods/Functions to help me out but I havent found any.